# How can i get JSON data from a PUSH notification in Appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, notifications, appium

I am trying to automate a mobile application, using android, java and appium.

I am receiving a PUSH notification, which contains data from a JSON. Is there any way to get that data using appium, or something like that?

Im using this method to get the notifications:

```
((AndroidDriver) driver).openNotifications();

ArrayList<MobileElement> allnotifications = (ArrayList<MobileElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("android:id/title"));

for (MobileElement m : allnotifications) {
    System.out.println(m.getText());
    if(m.getText().contains("Zona Kit2-P1:  armado totalmente")){
        System.out.println("Notificación de Armado Encontrada Corretamente");
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Appium, only the UI can be tested. If you want to get your data from a JSON object you can use the [rest assured library](http://rest-assured.io)